# REST DELETE should not require input Json?

Tags: json, rest, http-delete

I ran into a REST API at work (developed by another team) and noticed a couple of the DELETE api required Json object (list of ids to be deleted).  Is this one of the standard REST DELETE?  The DELETE I am used to does not require input Json.  Thanks in advance to your replies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [HTTP Semantics document](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-p2-semantics-25#page-29):

```
   A payload within a DELETE request message has no defined semantics;
   sending a payload body on a DELETE request might cause some existing
   implementations to reject the request.
```

Therefore, the existence or usage of a payload in a RESTful DELETE is implementation-specific.

However, RESTful deletes using the DELETE verb usually use the resource id in the URL:

```
DELETE /resource/{id}
```

In your description, it sounds like the list of ids to be deleted is passed in the payload. In this case, I think it would be more appropriate to use POST:

```
POST /resource?action=deletelist
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply.  I too feel that requiring payload on DELETE seems to break convention of REST DELETE.  What's more is that custom test codes are needed for a DELETE that requires payload.